# Threads in for cycle

Tags: javafx

I am getting system out println of variable "j" up to ten times in a row, but I don't see any reason for it.

Here is my code:

```
copyFolderButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String dateStart = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
                j = 0.00;
                ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                s.schedule(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        List<String> finallist = copyList.getItems();
                        totalComputersCopy = copyList.getItems().size();
                        successRateCopy = 0;
                        double a = 1.00;
                        double i = (1.00 / finallist.size());
                        ArrayList<String> selectedIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
                        try {
                            for (String row : finallist) {
                                a++;
                                j = j + i;

                                if (a % 10 == 0) {
                                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                                }
                                System.out.println(a);

                                copythread = new Thread("" + a) {

                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            System.out.println(j);
                                            javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> copyGauge.setValue(j * 100));
                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        }
                                        Process p;
                                        try {
                                            String pathRaw = copyFolderPath.getText();
                                            pathRaw = pathRaw.replace(":", "$");

                                            if (pathRaw != null && pathRaw.length() > 0 && pathRaw.charAt(pathRaw.length() - 1) == '\\') {
                                                pathRaw = pathRaw.substring(0, pathRaw.length() - 1);
                                            }

                                            String source = copyFolderSource.getText();

                                            if (source != null && source.length() > 0 && source.charAt(source.length() - 1) == '\\') {
                                                source = source.substring(0, source.length() - 1);
                                            }

                                            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("172.217.23.206");
                                            boolean b = ia.isReachable(2000);

                                            if (b) {
                                                //System.out.println(j*100);

                                                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "powershell -Command \"Copy-Item '" + source + "' -Destination '" + "\\\\" + row + "\\" + pathRaw + "' -Recurse -Verbose\"");
                                                p = builder.start();
                                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                                                StringBuilder builders = new StringBuilder();
                                                String line = null;
                                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                                                    builders.append(line);
                                                    builders.append("\n");

                                                }
                                                String DeleteLog = builders.toString();
                                                if (DeleteLog.trim().isEmpty()) {
                                                    successRateCopy++;
                                                    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> copyFolderLog.appendText(row + ": " + "Succesfully copied" + "\n"));
                                                } else {
                                                    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> copyFolderLog.appendText(row + ": " + DeleteLog + "\n"));
                                                }
                                                p.waitFor(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                                p.destroy();

                                            } else {
                                                javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> copyFolderLog.appendText("Cannot reach " + row + "\n"));
                                                System.out.println("Cannot reach " + row + "\n");

                                            }
                                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                                            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                            System.out.println(ex.toString());
                                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                        } finally {
                                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                copythread.start();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        } finally {

                            while (copythread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                            }
                            String successRateLog = String.valueOf(successRateCopy);
                            String failedRateLog = String.valueOf(totalComputersCopy - successRateCopy);
                            String dateStop = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                            Date d1 = null;
                            Date d2 = null;
                            try {
                                d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
                                d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

                                //in milliseconds
                                long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

                                long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
                                long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                                long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;

                                if ((diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24) != 0) {
                                    deleteTime = "Total time: " + String.valueOf(diffHours) + " hours, " + String.valueOf(diffMinutes) + " minutes, " + String.valueOf(diffSeconds) + " seconds";
                                } else {
                                    if ((diff / (60 * 1000) % 60) != 0) {
                                        deleteTime = "Total time: " + String.valueOf(diffMinutes) + " minutes, " + String.valueOf(diffSeconds) + " seconds";
                                    } else {
                                        if ((diff / 1000 % 60) != 0) {
                                            deleteTime = "Total time: " + String.valueOf(diffSeconds) + " seconds";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {

                                VBox container = new VBox();
                                container.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
                                Label icon = new Label();
                                Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/copyicon.png"));
                                icon.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
                                container.getChildren().add(icon);
                                Notifications.create()
                                        .darkStyle()
                                        .title("Copy Folder")
                                        .text("Workcomplete!" + "\n" + deleteTime + "\n" + "Success: " + successRateLog + "\n" + "Failed: " + failedRateLog)
                                        .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(30))
                                        .graphic(container)
                                        .show();
                            }
                            );
                        }
                    }

                }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        });
```

I am not sure that this is the best way on how to play with threads. It's working good, but I am aware what's wrong with printing variables in my code, it looks like this:

```
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
0.03333333333333333
7.0
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04666666666666667
8.0
9.0
0.060000000000000005
0.060000000000000005
0.060000000000000005
10.0
11.0
12.0
13.0
14.0
15.0
16.0
17.0
18.0
19.0
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
0.12666666666666668
```

"A" is printing ok, but "j" grows to ten lines and keeps on them.

Comment: I am using powershell because of copying folders to remote computers. So you can copy folder to many computers at once, limited with pause - thread.sleep() when number of threads was reached. I dont want to wait until every command was done, thats why i am creating more threads.